# How to load forge viewer in web application

Tags: autodesk-viewer, autodesk, viewer, forge

We have working on forge viewer to display the Revit models in our web application.And we have completed the following on code behind bucket ,token generate and translate without any error upto the file is ready.
Then URN number also passing to client side viewer function.

In header section we are using below scripts.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.3.7/themes/default/style.min.css" />
<!-- Autodesk Forge Viewer files -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/style.min.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.min.js"></script>
```

when loading function **launchViewer(urn)**
1)we are not able to get into this function getForgeToken() function.Also the uploaded file not loaded in viewer.
2)we have included the above header tag scripts in offline(we have created separate js,css and added in page).This is also we are not able to view the file in forge viewer.

we dont know why the launchViewer(urn) function is not loaded.

Please help on this to view the file.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are some error within your js code, this should work. Please refer to the simple framework sample https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.viewmodels/blob/master/js/ForgeViewer.js, or maybe you can paste your js code so we can help check.